# Call other process after executing a blocking process in shell

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, job-control, jobs

I have a process that is blocking in nature. It is executed first. In order to execute the second process, I moved the first process to the background and executed the second process. Using the wait statement, I am waiting in the terminal. However, it seems that upon exiting the shell (pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), the first process was not exited smoothly. Below is the shell script:

**execute.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# start process one in background
python3 -m http.server 8086 & 

# start second process
firefox "http://localhost:8086/index.html"
 
wait
```

I found a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326026/170921) but it seems not working properly. Basically, when I call `./execute.sh` a second time, the server says "Address already in use". It means the server could not exit peacefully. On the other hand, if I execute the sever manually in a terminal, it exits smoothly.

Comment: I'm guessing your python command just starts a web server?  I'm assuming there is nothing to stop your web server so this script would never actually exit unless you press ctrl+c right?

Comment: @jesse_b: You are right. You can replace the server with an infinite loop that can exit with ctrl+c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also trap for an interrupt to ensure the process is killed if ctrl+c is pressed

```
#!/bin/sh

trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c () {
    kill "$bpid"
    exit
}

# start process one in background
python3 -m http.server 8086 &
bpid=$!

# start second process
firefox "http://localhost:8086/index.html"
 
wait
```

Comment: I need to check your suggestion. However, I wonder, it is ok to kill a process? Can the process (server in this case) release the resources (port number in this case) and exit smoothly in this way?

Comment: @RaviJoshi: The default signal from kill is SIGTERM (15) which gives the process the ability to cleanup after itself and exit gracefully vs SIGKILL (9) which immediately kills the process.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is a nice way to catch ctrl+c and then kill the process. Works smoothly with a graceful exit. May I know more about the `bpid`? I can't see a `man` page for `bpid` in ubuntu 20.04 LTS though.

Comment: `bpid` is just an arbitrary variable name in this case.  It is being set with `$!` which will expand to the PID of the last executed background process.

Answer (score 2):

Kill the Python program after Firefox exits.

Off the top of my head:

```
#!/bin/sh

# start process one in background
python3 -m http.server 8086 & 
pid=$!

# start second process
firefox "http://localhost:8086/index.html"

kill "$!"
wait         # wait for it to actually exit
             # if it ignores SIGTERM, this'll hang
```

Or, since it seems the Firefox process started from the script doesn't actually run on the foreground (but probably just signals an existing `firefox` process to open a new window), that won't work.

But we can e.g. wait for input from the user instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

# start process one in background
python3 -m http.server 8086 & 
pid=$!

# start second process
firefox "http://localhost:8086/index.html"

echo "Started Python HTTP server"
echo "Press enter to close it"
read tmp

echo "Asking the Python HTTP server to terminate"

kill "$!"
wait         # wait for it to actually exit
             # if it ignores SIGTERM, this'll hang

echo "Done."
```

Another solution would be to implement an idle timer in the Python HTTP server. Have it wake up every N minutes to see if it's been M minutes or more since it last received a request, and exit if so.
Just don't make M too short or it'll die when you go for a short break.

Comment: I need to check your suggestion. However, I wonder, it is ok to kill a process? Can the process (server in this case) release the resources (port number in this case) and exit smoothly in this way?

Comment: @RaviJoshi, the network socket and such resources are managed by the kernel, which will clean them up when the process dies. (It has to, some process could also just segfault.) So that's not an issue. Any bookkeeping the program itself needs to do is different. (E.g. if it has some data in memory that needs to be written out, or if it wants to write a log entry about exiting.) But the SIGTERM signal that `kill` sends by default can be caught by the receiving process, so it can do whatever work it needs before exiting. Think of it a polite request to exit. SIGKILL is the unpolite one.

Comment: @RaviJoshi, I haven't done it in Python, but I'd go with a search on something like "python catch sigterm". There seems to be some samples e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully

Comment: Thank you very much. There is an issue with it. The first process is killed after opening the second. However, I should have said earlier that the first process is required to run the second process. My apologies for the inconvenience. Here is my upvote for your suggestion and explanation as well.

Comment: @RaviJoshi, yes, I figured that Firefox instance was supposed to access the server provided by the Python program. Now, if it was an ordinary program, it should work like I showed, you can try if you replace `firefox` with something like `cat`. But I'm guessing the issue is that the Firefox process that starts doesn't actually keep running, but only signals the existing Firefox in the background to open a new window. You could try to see if it changes if you close Firefox completely and then run the script, it might run its main work in the process started from the script then.

Comment: But yeah, in general, I think we need another workaround. I'm not sure how easy or possible it is to monitor when that particular Firefox window/tab closes, so I guess it's easier to just wait for user input, see edit.